# How to count the number of row conditional to multiple character criteria?

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements, character, criteria

I have a data frame in R like this :

```
ID     Type
---------------------------
1      Green-Red-Red-Green
2      Pink-Blue-Red-Red
3      Green-Green-Red
4      Pink-Blue-Blue-Green
5      Red-Red-Red-Green
```

So, I want to count the number of row containing the words Green and Red but not Pink and Blue.

In this case, the number would be 3 (3 rows, indeed when ID = 1,3 and 5).

I don't find how I can do it with multiple criteria and with characters. How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
 `library(data.table)`  

 `dt <- as.data.table(data_frame) # transform your data frame to a data table 
  nrow(dt[(Type%like%"Green") & (Type%like%"Red" & !Type%like%"Pink") & 
 (Type%like%"Blue"),]) # & stands for AND, ! stands for NOT`
```

**UPDATE according to question in comment**

This will give you the number of characters between "Pink" and "Blue"

`string <- "Pink-Green-Blue-Red"
tmp <- str_match(string, "Pink(.*?)Blue")
nchar(tmp[,2])`.

So you can do

```
dt[,tmp:=str_match(Type, "Pink(.*?)Blue")]
nrow(dt[!is.na(tmp)])
```

Comment: No problem. You can mark your question as answered :)

Comment: And I have another issue.

If I want the number of row when pink appears before blue ? How I can make a condition under the location of the words ?

Comment: exactly before blue ? If yes, then you could do `%like%"Pink-Blue"`

Comment: Not exactly, Red or Green could be between. I just want Pink before Blue in the list. I tried to do it with the function sum but I don't know if it is correct. I had END at the end of each list and I compute this

Comment: sum((grepl("Pink-Blue", dt$Type) & !grepl("Pink-END", dt$Type)) | 
      (grepl("Pink-Green", dt$Type) & grepl("Blue", dt$Type)& !grepl("Pink-END",dt $Type))
    | (grepl("Pink-Red", dt$Type) & grepl("Blue", dt$Type)& !grepl("Pink-END", dt$Type)))

Answer (score 0):

You can play with regex as well:

```
sum(grepl("Green", dt$Type) & grepl("Red", dt$Type) & !grepl("Pink", dt$Type) & !grepl("Blue", dt$Type))
```